# Fetching a value as a separate column depending on another column

Tags: mysql

My data looks like:

```
col1    col2    attr    val
ABC     123      A      10
ABC     123      B      18
XYZ     123      A      5
XYZ     123      B      11
ABC     888      A      24
ABC     888      B      13
XYZ     888      A      25
.
.
.
```

Basically various combinations of col1,col2 exist; and corresponding to each `attr` associated with them, they have a separate record for `val`.

I need the output in the form:

```
col1    col2   A_val    B_val
ABC     123     10       18
XYZ     123     5        11
```

(for each unique combination of `col1 col2`)

This sort of a query is new territory for me, so I'm not sure where to start. It would probably involve something like a `CASE WHEN attr='A' THEN val END as A_val` but I'm not sure how to structure it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
  SELECT col1, 
         col2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr='A' THEN val END) A_val,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr='B' THEN val END) B_val
    FROM table_name
GROUP BY col1,
         col2
```

As `NULL`s come last in a descending ordering, and `CASE` returns `NULL` for no condition matched, `MAX` will give you the correct attribute for each column.